# Does it always have to be I_E = I_B + I_C for a transistor circuit?

Tags: transistors, common-base

I found this common base configuration of an npn transistor, and here it is - I_B = I_E + I_C, and the circuit seems moving. Is this considered a transistor circuit or not?

the video - https://streamable.com/e6j4vo

Comment: Current into a node is always equal to current out of a node, if it wasn't then electrons would be piling up somewhere. That's true for anything, not just transistors.

Comment: Please use the circuit editor built into this site. When editing the question, press Ctrl-M where you want to put a schematic. The schematic editor also does real-time DC simulation, so you can just mouse over various parts of the circuit to see the voltages and currents, and you can add voltmeter and ammeters that display up-to-date DC solution. You'll need a laptop/desktop machine as there's no mobile interface for CircuitLab. Links to third-party sites are a bad idea since they always die after a while leaving a lot of posts useless. No need for an animation to show the schematic!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

\$ -I_B = I_E + I_C\$ is true for any circuit with only three nodes labelled B, E and C whether there is a transistor in there or not.

Your circuit doesn't do anything useful.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD1qaG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuit.*

You are using the transistor as a pair of diodes so there is no transistor action involved.

If you're going to try this for real you'll need a transistor that can handle a base current of about 3 A.